# XSLT: merging multiple sequences into a single sequence

Tags: xml, variables, xpath, foreach, xslt-1.0

Suppose I have an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<everything>
    <something>
        <part>
            <prop type="a">1</prop>
            <prop type="b">2</prop>
            <prop type="c">3</prop>
        </part>
        <part>
            <prop type="a">4</prop>
            <!--No b!-->
            <prop type="c">5</prop>
        </part>
    </something>
    <something>
        <part>
            <prop type="a">6</prop>
            <prop type="b">7</prop>
            <!--No c!-->
        </part>
    </something>
</everything>
```

And I want output like this:

```
<something>
   <props type="a">14</props>
   <props type="b">2?</props>
   <props type="c">35</props>
</something>

<something>
   <props type="a">6</props>
   <props type="b">7</props>
   <props type="c">?</props>
</something>
```

In other words, first I want to know what all the `prop/@type`s in the document are. In this case 'a','b', and 'c'. I already found a solution for that part, which I will gloss over for this question. Next, for each "something" I want to iterate through those expected prop elements and merge together all the props of that type in the current "something" element, under a new element with the name `props`. If one of the expected prop elements is not found inside a part element, then insert a question mark.

Here is my best attempt, below. I think there are at least two problems with it. For one, inside the scope of the `<xsl:for-each select="$allTheProps/prop">̀` loop, I can't do `select="part"` like I normally could right outside the $allTheProps loop. The other problem is I don't think you can have a variable in a path pattern thingy, so I can't test if `@type=$nodeType`. The end result is that my `props` elements are just empty. How can I get around these problems?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="allTheProps">
        <!--These elements are actually dynamically generated
            based on all prop types found in the document-->
        <prop type="a"></prop>
        <prop type="b"></prop>
        <prop type="c"></prop>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="something">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!--for each found type-->
            <xsl:for-each select="$allTheProps/prop">
                <xsl:variable name="nodeType" select="@type"/>

                <props>
                    <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$nodeType" />
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <!--merge the props from each part of a something node-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="part">
                       <xsl:value-of select="prop[@type=$nodeType]"/>
                       <xsl:if test="not(prop[@type=$nodeType])">?</xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </props>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: You haven't made it clear whether you want an XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 solution. Please use the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot that the first `<xsl:for-each select="$allTheProps/prop">` changes the context to the variable `allTheProps` and therefore your next `<xsl:for-each select="part">` is executed in the context of this variable and **not** in that of the template as you expect it(`part`). So you end up with an empty nodeset in your `for-each`.

A solution is to preserve the context in a variable - here I named it `subTree` - and accessing this variable. So only two minor changes make your code work as desired.

```
<xsl:template match="something">
    <xsl:variable name="subTree" select="*" />        <!-- save context -->

    <xsl:copy>
        <!--for each found type-->
        <xsl:for-each select="$allTheProps/prop">
            <xsl:variable name="nodeType" select="@type"/>

            <props>
                <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="$nodeType" />
                </xsl:attribute>

                <!--merge the props from each part of a something node-->
                <xsl:for-each select="$subTree">     <!-- access variable -->
                   <xsl:value-of select="prop[@type=$nodeType]"/>
                   <xsl:if test="not(prop[@type=$nodeType])">?</xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </props>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Brilliant. And I guess I was wrong, you can use a variable in the `select` and `test` patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do

```
<xsl:template match="something">
  <something>
    <xsl:merge>
      <xsl:merge-source for-each="part" select="prop">
        <xsl:merge-key select="@type"/>
      </xsl:merge-source>
      <xsl:merge-action>
        <props type="{current-merge-key()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="string-join(current-merge-group(), '')"/>
        </props>
      </xsl:merge-action>
    </xsl:merge>
  </something>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT 3.0 sounds lovely. Unfortunately I needed a 1.0 solution. And in a way the 1.0 solution is easier because it doesn't require knowing anything more than variables and for-each loops.

Comment: That's fine. Next time you need a 1.0 solution, please say so.